# how to convert for loop results in json

Tags: php, json

I Want to convert this php results in to JSON.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < (count($getnodays)); $i++)
{
    $category = $getctgry[$i];
    $Priority = $getpriotity[$i];
    $NoOfDays = $getnodays[$i];
    $StDate = $date1[$i];
    $EdDate = $date2[$i];
}
```

Results Required to be in :

```
{ 
    "Category": "Category", 
    "Priority": "Priority1", 
    "StDate": "1/1/2016", 
    "EdDate": "5/1/2018" 
},{ 
    "Category": "Category", 
    "Priority": "Priority1", 
    "StDate": "1/1/2016", 
    "EdDate": "5/1/2018" 
},{ 
    "Category": "Category", 
    "Priority": "Priority1", 
    "StDate": "1/1/2016", 
    "EdDate": "5/1/2018" 
}
```

Comment: What would you expect if there are multiple days?

Comment: No no, what output would you expect....

Comment: I need the output like {
     "Category": "Category",
     "Priority": "Priority1",
     "StDate": "1/1/2016",
     "EdDate": "5/1/2018"
},{
     "Category": "Category",
     "Priority": "Priority1",
     "StDate": "1/1/2016",
     "EdDate": "5/1/2018"
},{
     "Category": "Category",
     "Priority": "Priority1",
     "StDate": "1/1/2016",
     "EdDate": "5/1/2018"
}

Comment: What Jon is trying to say is: Your example only shows the result from one iteration of your for loop. Show us what you want for at least 2 iterations

Comment: So you want to generate **illegal** JSON for you?

Comment: That's not valid JSON, but whatever, just use arrays. Create a new array on each loop, set the key to the labels you want, and the value to the index of the var (as you have), then add that array to a collection array, finally json_encode the collection array to get valid JSON representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop, create a new array occurance each iteration.

Then use `json_encode()` to turn that array into a valid JSON string.

```
$json = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < (count($getnodays)); $i++) {
    $json[] = ['Category'   => $getctgry[$i],
                'Priority'  => $getpriotity[$i],
                'NoOfDays'  => $getnodays[$i],
                'StDate'    => $date1[$i],
                'EdDate'    => $date2[$i],
            ];
}
echo json_encode($json);
```